# Antlr3 grammar generates parsering error on encountering the Pound char

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

Antlr-3 generating an error on encountering the Pound char ("**£**") of the French language, which is equivalent char of Hash "**#**" char of English, even the Unicode value for three special characters **@**, **#**, and **$** are specified in lexer/parser rule.

**FYI:** The Unicode value of Pound char (of the French language) = The Unicode value of Hash char (of ENGLISH language).

**The lexer/parser rules:**

```
grammar SimpleCalc;

options
{
  k        = 8;
  language = Java;
  //filter   = true;
}
 
tokens {
    PLUS    = '+' ;
    MINUS   = '-' ;
    MULT    = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
}
 
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
expr    : n1=NUMBER ( exp = ( PLUS | MINUS )  n2=NUMBER )* 
{
  if ($exp.text.equals("+"))
   System.out.println("Plus Result = " + $n1.text + $n2.text);
  else
   System.out.println("Minus Result = " + $n1.text + $n2.text);
}
;
 
/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
NUMBER  : (DIGIT)+ ;
 
WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
 
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' | '£' | ('\u0040' | '\u0023' | '\u0024');
```

The text file also reading in UTF-8 as:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            args = new String[1];
            args[0] = new String("antlr_test.txt");
            SimpleCalcLexer lex = new SimpleCalcLexer(new ANTLRFileStream(args[0], "UTF-8"));
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
            
            SimpleCalcParser parser = new SimpleCalcParser(tokens);
            
            parser.expr();
            //System.out.println(tokens);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The input file is having only 1 line:

```
 £3 + 4£
```

the error is:

```
antlr_test.txt line 1:1 no viable alternative at character '£'
antlr_test.txt line 1:7 no viable alternative at character '£'
```

What is wrong with my approach?
or did I miss something?

Comment: Make sure your .g3 file is encoded in UTF-8 as well as the input file or driver. I just copied the input string and pasted it to a file, and it did not encode the input as UTF-8. After importing the grammar into Antlr4 and fixing the encoding, it parses fine.

Comment: @kaby76, 
My actual grammar is of Antlr-3. 
So, is any special setting is required to make .g file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: No, you're doing it correct. You might not have re-generated lexer and parser classes recently. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce what you describe. When I test your grammar without modifications, I get a `NumberFormatException`, which is expected, because `Integer.parseInt("£3")` cannot succeed.

When I change your embedded code into this:

```java
{
  if ($exp.text.equals("+"))
   System.out.println("Result = " + (Integer.parseInt($n1.text.replaceAll("\\D", "")) + Integer.parseInt($n2.text.replaceAll("\\D", ""))));
  else
   System.out.println("Result = " + (Integer.parseInt($n1.text.replaceAll("\\D", "")) - Integer.parseInt($n2.text.replaceAll("\\D", ""))));
}
```

and regenerate lexer and parser classes (something you might not have done) and rerun the driver code, I get the following output:

```
Result = 7
```

### EDIT

Perhaps the pound sign in the grammar is the issue? What if you try:

```
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' | '\u00A3' | ('\u0040' | '\u0023' | '\u0024');
```

instead of:

```
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9' | '£' | ('\u0040' | '\u0023' | '\u0024');
```

?

Comment: Yes, that I missed to correct the Integer.parseInt() in parser rule action.


Now I regenerated the lexer/parser classes, but still getting the same error:

`antlr_test.txt line 1:1 no viable alternative at character '£'`
`antlr_test.txt line 1:7 no viable alternative at character '£'`
`Result = 7`
`

Comment: Antlr3 Project (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16P8Qyf52zKj25GlxbyPNN_Ic0yLSHkQH?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check my EDIT @Kishore

Comment: Thanks, @Bart,
I missed to specify the Unicode value '\u00A3'.